# Show geotiff image in OpenLayers with Vue.js (composition API)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openlayers, geotiff

Thanks for reading my question!

I'm trying to show a geotiff image from an url, like in this example:
[OpenLayers Workshop](https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/cog/true-color.html)

But I want it to work in Vue.js 3 with composition API.
In my code example, the map is showing, but not the image layer.
There is no error message.
It looks like the data is not loaded correctly, or it is still a promise.

Does somebody know where my mistake is?

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import "ol/ol.css";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import GeoTIFF from "ol/source/GeoTIFF";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import WebGLTile from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile.js';

const map = ref(null);

const source = new GeoTIFF({
    sources: [
        {
            url: 'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/32/U/NA/2022/9/S2B_32UNA_20220923_0_L2A/TCI.tif',
        },
    ],
});

const OSMlayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM(),
});

async function addTileLayer() {
    const ImageLayer = new TileLayer({
        source: source,
    });
    map.value.addLayer(ImageLayer);
}

onMounted(async () => {
    map.value = new Map({
        target: "map",
        layers: [OSMlayer],
        view: new View({
            center: fromLonLat([9.93, 49.78]),
            zoom: 9,
        }),
    });
    await addTileLayer();
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
#map {
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You must use a WebGLTile layer for a GeoTIFF source.

Comment: You will also need proj4 and the projection definition if the source in a different projection to the view.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thried both things but independent from one another, but with both, it works :)